# File transfer using smack in android apps.

Tags: android, smack

**This error come in log.**

```
from='kutbi1@360degree/Smack' to='akash@360degree/Smack' type='error' id='hK1L6-5'>
<si xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/si' id='jsi_191216212994140179' mime-type='image/png' profile='http://jabber.org/protocol/si/profile/file-transfer'>
<file xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/si/profile/file-transfer' name='this_old_house.png' size='12623'>
<desc>You won&apos;t believe this!</desc></file>
<feature xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/feature-neg'>
<x xmlns='jabber:x:data' type='form'><field var='stream-method' type='list-multi'>
 <option><value>http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams</value></option>
 <option><value>http://jabber.org/protocol/ibb</value></option>
</field>
 </x>
</feature>
</si>
<error code='503' type='cancel'>
<service-unavailable xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas'/>
</error></iq>
```

I have use following code here

```
    ServiceDiscoveryManager sdm = ServiceDiscoveryManager.getInstanceFor(Main.connection);
    if (sdm == null)
        sdm = new ServiceDiscoveryManager(Main.connection);
    sdm.addFeature("http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info");
    sdm.addFeature("jabber:iq:privacy");

   FileTransferNegotiator.setServiceEnabled(Main.connection, true);
   FileTransferManager manager = new FileTransferManager(Main.connection);
  OutgoingFileTransfer transfer = manager.createOutgoingFileTransfer(id
           + "/Smack");

   Log.i("transfere file", "outgoingfiletransfere is created");
    try{
        //OutgoingFileTransfer.setResponseTimeout(60000);
        transfer.sendFile(new File(txt_file.getText().toString()), "You won't believe this!");

        if (transfer.getStatus().equals(Status.cancelled)
                || transfer.getStatus().equals(Status.refused)) {
                Log.d("Cancel", ""+transfer.getError());
                System.out.println("Cancelled!!! " + transfer.getError());
            }

        Log.i("transfere file", "sending file");
        Log.d("FTTRY", "m in ft TRY");
        btn_transfer.setText("Browse");
        txt_file.setText("click on browse n Select File");
        send_flag = true;
    }catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("FTCATCH", "m in ft catch");
        btn_transfer.setText("BrowseC");
        send_flag = true;
    }

    while(!transfer.isDone()) {
        try{
           Thread.sleep(1000);
        }catch (Exception e) {
        }
          Log.i("transfere file", "sending file status "
                      + transfer.getStatus() + "progress: "
                      + transfer.getProgress());
       if(transfer.getStatus().equals(Status.error)) {
             System.out.println("ERROR!!! " + transfer.getError());
       } else {
             System.out.println(transfer.getStatus());
             System.out.println(transfer.getProgress());
             Log.d("PROG", "m in ft progress");
       }
      try{
       Thread.sleep(1000);
      }catch (Exception e) {
    }
 }
```

Comment: which version of smack are you using?

Comment: asmack15 
i try from 5 days but still m not abble to transfer file through smack.
if u have any idea regarding this please help

Comment: @Hussain i have use this version of smack :-asmack-android-7-beem.jar

Comment: @Akash : Try this solution http://community.igniterealtime.org/thread/30695

Comment: @Hussain i have try this link .but my problem is not solve...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the same issue by doing this following procedure.

I am using **asmack-2010.05.07-source** in eclipse for android-2.2.

Go for ProviderManager class in the asmack. Replace the following code

```
Enumeration providerEnum = classLoader.getResources(
                        "/META-INF/smack.providers");
```

with this

```
Enumeration providerEnum = classLoader.getResources(
                        "/data/smack.providers");
```

After this you need to do a patch. Add the following function before you creating the 
`new XMPPConnection`. You can call this function by

```
 configure(ProviderManager.getInstance());
```

This is the method.

```
public void configure(ProviderManager pm) {

    //  Private Data Storage
    pm.addIQProvider("query","jabber:iq:private", new PrivateDataManager.PrivateDataIQProvider());


    //  Time
    try {
        pm.addIQProvider("query","jabber:iq:time", Class.forName("org.jivesoftware.smackx.packet.Time"));
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        Log.w("TestClient", "Can't load class for org.jivesoftware.smackx.packet.Time");
    }

    //  Roster Exchange
    pm.addExtensionProvider("x","jabber:x:roster", new RosterExchangeProvider());

    //  Message Events
    pm.addExtensionProvider("x","jabber:x:event", new MessageEventProvider());

    //  Chat State
    pm.addExtensionProvider("active","http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates", new ChatStateExtension.Provider());

    pm.addExtensionProvider("composing","http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates", new ChatStateExtension.Provider());

    pm.addExtensionProvider("paused","http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates", new ChatStateExtension.Provider());

    pm.addExtensionProvider("inactive","http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates", new ChatStateExtension.Provider());

    pm.addExtensionProvider("gone","http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates", new ChatStateExtension.Provider());

    //  XHTML
    pm.addExtensionProvider("html","http://jabber.org/protocol/xhtml-im", new XHTMLExtensionProvider());

    //  Group Chat Invitations
    pm.addExtensionProvider("x","jabber:x:conference", new GroupChatInvitation.Provider());

    //  Service Discovery # Items    
    pm.addIQProvider("query","http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items", new DiscoverItemsProvider());

    //  Service Discovery # Info
    pm.addIQProvider("query","http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info", new DiscoverInfoProvider());

    //  Data Forms
    pm.addExtensionProvider("x","jabber:x:data", new DataFormProvider());

    //  MUC User
    pm.addExtensionProvider("x","http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#user", new MUCUserProvider());

    //  MUC Admin    
    pm.addIQProvider("query","http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#admin", new MUCAdminProvider());


    //  MUC Owner    
    pm.addIQProvider("query","http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#owner", new MUCOwnerProvider());

    //  Delayed Delivery
    pm.addExtensionProvider("x","jabber:x:delay", new DelayInformationProvider());

    //  Version
    try {
        pm.addIQProvider("query","jabber:iq:version", Class.forName("org.jivesoftware.smackx.packet.Version"));
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        //  Not sure what's happening here.
    }

    //  VCard
    pm.addIQProvider("vCard","vcard-temp", new VCardProvider());

    //  Offline Message Requests
    pm.addIQProvider("offline","http://jabber.org/protocol/offline", new OfflineMessageRequest.Provider());

    //  Offline Message Indicator
    pm.addExtensionProvider("offline","http://jabber.org/protocol/offline", new OfflineMessageInfo.Provider());

    //  Last Activity
    pm.addIQProvider("query","jabber:iq:last", new LastActivity.Provider());

    //  User Search
    pm.addIQProvider("query","jabber:iq:search", new UserSearch.Provider());

    //  SharedGroupsInfo
    pm.addIQProvider("sharedgroup","http://www.jivesoftware.org/protocol/sharedgroup", new SharedGroupsInfo.Provider());

    //  JEP-33: Extended Stanza Addressing
    pm.addExtensionProvider("addresses","http://jabber.org/protocol/address", new MultipleAddressesProvider());

    //   FileTransfer
    pm.addIQProvider("si","http://jabber.org/protocol/si", new StreamInitiationProvider());

    pm.addIQProvider("query","http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams", new BytestreamsProvider());

    pm.addIQProvider("open","http://jabber.org/protocol/ibb", new IBBProviders.Open());

    pm.addIQProvider("close","http://jabber.org/protocol/ibb", new IBBProviders.Close());

    pm.addExtensionProvider("data","http://jabber.org/protocol/ibb", new IBBProviders.Data());

    //  Privacy
    pm.addIQProvider("query","jabber:iq:privacy", new PrivacyProvider());

    pm.addIQProvider("command", "http://jabber.org/protocol/commands", new AdHocCommandDataProvider());
    pm.addExtensionProvider("malformed-action", "http://jabber.org/protocol/commands", new AdHocCommandDataProvider.MalformedActionError());
    pm.addExtensionProvider("bad-locale", "http://jabber.org/protocol/commands", new AdHocCommandDataProvider.BadLocaleError());
    pm.addExtensionProvider("bad-payload", "http://jabber.org/protocol/commands", new AdHocCommandDataProvider.BadPayloadError());
    pm.addExtensionProvider("bad-sessionid", "http://jabber.org/protocol/commands", new AdHocCommandDataProvider.BadSessionIDError());
    pm.addExtensionProvider("session-expired", "http://jabber.org/protocol/commands", new AdHocCommandDataProvider.SessionExpiredError());
}
```

I got the solution from the following link http://code.google.com/p/asmack/issues/detail?id=23

Comment: i have tried this..But my problem still here. this is not solve.

Comment: How to include the asmack library for my android project. i am getting so many errors

Answer (score 1):

Thanks ,
But I solved my problems ..
The problem is that opposite user is not logged in. so I have just install sparkx clinet form http://www.igniterealtime.org/downloads/download-landing.jsp?file=spark/spark_2_6_3.exe and logged in using other user and that's it.

Following is full working code.
you need to set up your server and port in General.java
also I have fixed users in activity so you need to change it as per your configuration.

https://sites.google.com/site/fancifulandroid/android-projects/FiletransfarXMPP.rar?attredirects=0&d=1